# Price of european call option for different strike prices

Tags: option-pricing, european-options, zero-coupon, put

Consider two european put options with strike prices $K, J$ with $K<J$ and maturity $T$.
Then the no arbitrage assumption implies $P_{K}(0)<P_J(0)$, where $P_K(0)$ denotes the price of the put with strike $K$ at time $t=0$.

Proof: Assume otherwise, then  sell option with  strike $K$ and buy option with strike $S$, yielding a instant profit of $P_K(0) - P_S(0) \geq 0$. This can be invested in an risk free asset, i.e. buy $P_K(0) - P_S(0)/ B(0,T)$ zero coupon bonds. $B(0,T)$ denotes the price of such a bond with maturity $T$.

At maturity $T$ there are two cases to distinguish. If the underlying exeeds the strike $K$, there is nothing to do. In the other case you can sell the buyer of the put with strike $K$ the underlying for $K$ which can be financed by exercising the bought put recieving $J>K $.

So in each case you made a profit out of nothing.

I hope that is the right argument. My question is, whether it is possible to have $P_{K}(0)=P_J(0)$ for $K<J$.

Can this be the case if you have negative interest rates?

Comment: The payoff itself, $\max\{K-S_T,0\}$, is always monotone in the strike price $K$. So, you need a weird discount factor. Suppose time is discrete and interest rates are fixed. Then, $P(K)=\frac{1}{1+rT}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[\max\{K-S_T,0\}$. Suppose $T=1$ and $r=-150\%$, then put option prices would monotonically decline in the strike price. Of course, this is more than a pathological example. In continuous time, you need $r>-1$, so this kind of argument wouldn't apply to the Black-Scholes model, where puts are always monotone in $K$.

Comment: @Kevin Ok so there is no other possibility apart from negative interest rates? The proof for the normal case is right isn' it?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The option price is the expected discounted payoff. Because the payoff is monotone in $K$, you need the discount factor to flip monotonicity. This only works if discrete interest rates are super negative.

Comment: @Kevin. Thank you for your answer. This would also imply that that the price of the zero coupon bond $B(0,T) >1 $. So everything should make sense then.

Comment: You mentioned he Black-Scholes-Model. I wonder why the considered asset have to be Ito-processes. The reason might be that you have a larger set of integrands apart from only Brownian motion?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Itô processes. I only used the Black-Scholes model as an example for a time-continuous model. In these models, the discount factor (= zero coupon bond price) is non-negative and put option prices are always monotone in the strike price $K$.

Comment: Yes sorry.  I know that. I wanted to ask you that, so that I do not have to ask an extra question. Is the argument concerning a larger set of integrand right?

Comment: The result does not depend on any integrand. The stock price can be any semimartingale (or even more general if you can make sense of it). The payoff is monotone in $K$, regardless how you model the stock price. Thus, the only question is the sign of the discount factor. This, again, is independent of the model for the stock price.

Comment: Maybe my question was not precise enough. I am referring to $$S^0(t)=e^{rt}$$ and $$S^1(t)=se^{r+ \lambda - 0.5 \sigma^2)t + \sigma W(t)}$$. I know that Ito's formula implies that this assets are ineed Ito-processes, but I wanted whether this yields any advantage concerning computations?